# How to split one table column into two sub-columns with merged header and footer?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

How can I achieve this table in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: you can't split columns, but you can merge cells with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}`  where you need.

Comment: how can i make that table sir?

Comment: no.  i will not retype it. just write standard table and than i will help you further or you can wait that someone will do your task instead of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Criteria}}}                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Proposed}}                         & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Matching rate}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Remarks}} \\ \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                                                          & \textbf{Trial 1} & \textbf{Trial 2}                            &                                         &                                   \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}The device\\ works buggy\end{tabular}}          & Passed           & Passed                                      & 100\%                                   & Passed                            \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}That works\\ only to monitor bugs\end{tabular}} & Passed           & Passed                                      & 100\%                                   & Passed                            \\ \hline
        &                  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{Functionality}} & \textbf{100\%}                          & \textbf{Passed}                   \\ \cline{3-5} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which would give you:

[image]

**PS:** *[off-topic]* you having been asked the same class of questions, I think you should also put in a little bit of effort to understand how these things works (the packages in particular) `:-)`. Because, this is not a `do-it-for-me` site (as `@zarko` already emphasised). Atleast, for these type of questions, it would be great if you give a `MWE`.

Answer (score 4):

used @Raaja answer (+1) as op mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{Criteria}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Proposed}}
        & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{Matching rate}}
            & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\textbf{Remarks}}     \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \textbf{Trial 1}
        & \textbf{Trial 2}
            &   &                                   \\
    \hline
\makecell{The device\\ works buggy}
    & Passed    & Passed    & 100\% & Passed        \\
    \hline
\makecell{That works\\ only to monitor bugs}
     & Passed    & Passed    & 100\% & Passed        \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{Functionality}}
            & \textbf{100\%} & \textbf{Passed}      \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So mine is an intermediate question :-D (yay!!!). Nevertheless, nice alignments per se (+1)

Comment: @Raaja, you do job of op, which i wasn't willing to do. so, yes, i exploit you (your answer) :-)

Comment: I remember that is how I started using `TeX`. So looking back, I always prefer to give a head-up when an OP suffers to compose a `MWE` (but not repetitively ofc`;-)`). [off-topic] may be `you(r ...)` would be more devastating than `you (your ...)` `:-D`.